# How do I modify functions to insert each item in sorted order in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning about vectors and have gotten stuck on this question. This is a practice problem that I do NOT get credit for answering. It is an online class that doesn't offer much help and only grades a final project.An explanation is very much appreciated!

Modify the numsInsert function to insert each item in sorted order. The new program should output: 4 19 55 250

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void numsInsert(vector<int>& numsList, int newNum) {
   unsigned int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < numsList.size(); ++i) {
      if (newNum < numsList.at(i)) {
         // FIXME: insert newNum at element i
         break; // Exits the for loop
      }
   }

   // FIXME: change so executes if higher number NOT found
   // Change "true" to "i == ??" (determine what ?? should be)
   if (true) { // No higher number was found, so append to end
      numsList.push_back(newNum);

   }   
   return;
}

void numsPrint(const vector<int>& numsList) {
   unsigned int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < numsList.size(); ++i) {
      cout << " " << numsList.at(i) << endl;
   }  
   return;
}

int main() {
   vector<int> numsList;
   numsInsert(numsList, 55);
   numsInsert(numsList, 4);
   numsInsert(numsList, 250);
   numsInsert(numsList, 19);
   numsPrint (numsList);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need an explanation of what?  What don't you get?  What have you tried?

Comment: Read about `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you read the documentation on `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

For the first `FIXME`, place the following code:

```
numList.insert(numList.begin() + i, newNum);
```

This `insert`s at the `i`th position in `numList` the parameter `newNum`. `numList.begin()` returns an iterator to the beginning of `numList` and the `+ i` adjusts it foward by `i` positions (the first parameter of `insert()` is an iterator).

For the second `FIXME`, replace the `if` condition with:

```
if (i == numList.size()) { //...
```

If no higher number is found, `i` will be `==` the size of the vector `numList` (as this is the implicit stop condition of the previous loop).

For reference, you can see the vector API at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). This is what I referred to in order to create this answer.

Comment: Thank-you so much for answering my question and adding an additional reference. I think I was trying to cram too many lessons in that day and ended up with brain overload, where nothing was making sense anymore. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question thoroughly!!